# Do I need to make a reservation in a mountain hut in Slovakia in the Tatra mountains?

Tags: mountains, slovakia

I'd like to go trekking in the Tatra mountains in Slovakia, and sleep in mountain huts.

Do I need to make a reservation before the trip? Or can I reasonably expect to always get a place to sleep (even on the floor)? I've heard of people turned away from mountain huts in Poland because there were no free places, and I'm a bit anxious about that. At best I'd sleep in my tent, but AFAIK this is not allowed in Tatra.

Comment: As for polish mountains you will be never kicked out of the public refuge (PTTK). There is a private refuge in the polish east Tatra called "Murowaniec" which probably accounts for most of the bad stories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, a mountain hut should never send away a tired tourist, especially if he doesn't have a chance to reach another safe place before sundown. But in summer some of the huts are so full, that tourist need to sleep in dining room on the floor.

In Slovakia, the huts range from small, with capacity of 20 people, to large with capacity of over 100 people. I suggest checking [this Slovak page](http://www.vysoketatry.com/chaty/chaty.html) for information about the hut, find their phone number and under `KAPACITA UBYTOVANIA` you can check their capacity.

As for tents, most of Tatra area is a national park, and in such you are not allowed to camp or walk away from marked hiking tracks.